# CQL Query to return maximum value in a columnfamily

Tags: cassandra, max, cql

Please find below columnfamily rating. I have one below use case.
Column rating_total is having counter datatype and increments the value . I want to get
CQL Query to return maximum value in a columnfamily.

### Use Case

Top Rated Product.

### ColumnFamily

CREATE TABLE rating_count (
  ratingid uuid,
  rating_total counter,
  PRIMARY KEY (ratingid)
);

Please suggest if any process is available.

Answer (score 1):

The example here isn't exactly like your use case, but perhaps it will give you some ideas: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html